# \cite spills over into the margin

Tags: line-breaking, citing

As you can see at the picture, a citation spills over into the margin of my paper. How can I resolve the issue?

[image]

Comment: Use `\begin{sloppypar}....\end{sloppypar}` to that particular paragraph.

Comment: Can we please see how this particular citation is being produced?

Comment: Rephrase the sentence containing the citation to be on another place, for example the beginning of the sentence?

Comment: I used this command ~\cite{<key>} @GonzaloMedina

Comment: Then, I suggest doing as Kurt said: if possible, rephrase the sentence so that the citation moves to another place (not the end of the line).

Comment: Try [`\usepackage{microtype}`](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype)

Comment: Please show the bib entry used to generate this citation. Also, do you use citation management packages (such as `cite` or `natbib`) and `babel`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Other users have suggested general methods to deal with bad line breaks, namely

- loading the [`microtype`](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) package (should be done before resorting to other measures);
- enclosing the problematic paragraph in a `sloppypar` environment;
- rephrasing the paragraph (note that – due to TeX's line-breaking algorithm – shifting a single word might do).

In the case of numerical citations, I also suggest to simply allow line breaks before them, i.e., to replace the non-breaking space at the start of `~\cite{<key>}` with a normal space.

Comment: I prefer `\newcommand\spacecite{\penalty700\ \cite}`, and than saying `\spacecite{<key>}` (with no space before). This makes LaTeX try to avoid line-break before `\cite`, but only to some extent.

Comment: @tohecz I like the idea -- is the penalty value `700` a rule of thumb?

Comment: Certainly you want this penalty to be more than `\pretolerance` so that you more likely hyphenate than break before `\cite`. And you obviously want it less than `\hbadness` so that a line with a break at that place is not "bad". Then, the value is just a rule of thumb.

Comment: Is there any way to ensure that the entire piece is pushed onto the next line?  For example, in this case, I would like (ITU) [1] to be on the next line.

Answer (score 2):

I actually have one more suggestion. It seems that the word before the `\cite` is in English, whereas the document is in Italian (thanks Guido to correcting me).

You can try adding this to your preamble (notice that the last language passed to `babel` is the default one):

```
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
```

Then, you can do the following that may help:

```
\foreignlanguage{english}{Telecommunications Union}~\cite{<key>}
```

Comment: it is in Italian not Spanish, and also in the text there is (ITU) between the text in English and the citation.

Comment: Yeah, it seems I overseen the abbreviation. Still, this argument may be valid for other people seeking help here ;)

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain to me what have I done wrong?